# How to compute and plot the pdf from the empirical cdf?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, statistics, probability

I have two numpy arrays, one is an array of x values and the other an array of y values and together they give me the empirical cdf. E.g.:

```
plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues)
plt.show()
```

I assume the data needs to be smoothed somehow in order to give a smooth pdf.

[image]

I would like to plot the pdf. How can I do that?

The raw data is at: http://dpaste.com/1HVK5DR .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main problems: Your data seems to be quite noisy, and it is not equally spaced: The points at the low end are sampled quite densly, while the ponts at the high end are sampled quite sparsely. This can cause numerical issues.

So first I suggest resampling the data using a linear interpolation to get equaly spaced samples: (Note that all the snippets appended to eachother form the content of *one* python file.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from data import xvalues, yvalues #load data from file


print("#datapoints: {}".format(len(xvalues)))
#don't use every point if your computer is not very fast
xv = np.array(xvalues)[::5]
yv = np.array(yvalues)[::5]

#interpolate to have evenly space data
xi = np.linspace(xv.min(), xv.max(), 400)
yi = np.interp(xi, xv, yv)
```

Then, to *smoothen* the data, I suggest performing a RBF regression (=using an ["RBF Network"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network)). The idea is fiting a curve of the form

```
 c(t) = sum a(i) * phi(t - x(i))    #(not part of the program)
```

where `phi` is some radial basis function. (In theory we could use *any* functions.) To have a very smooth result I choose a very smooth function, namely a gaussian: `phi(x) = exp( - x^2/sigma^2)` where `sigma` is yet to be determined. The `x(i)` are just some nodes that we can define. If we have a smooth function, we just need a few nodes. The number of nodes also determines how much computation needs to be done. The `a(i)` are the coefficients we can optimize to get the best fit. In this case I just use a least squares approach.

Note that IF we can write a function in the form above, it is very easy to compute the derivative, it is just

```
 c(t) = sum a(i) * phi'(t - x(i))
```

where `phi'` is the derivative of `phi`.    #(not part of the program)

Regarding `sigma`: It is usually a good idea to choose it as a multiple of the step between the nodes we chose. The greater we choose `sigma`, the smoother the resulting function gets.

```
#set up rbf network
rbf_nodes = xv[::50][None, :]#use a subset of the x-values as rbf nodes
print("#rbfs: {}".format(rbf_nodes.shape[1]))
#estimate width of kernels:
sigma = 20  #greater = smoother, this is the primary parameter to play with
sigma *= np.max(np.abs(rbf_nodes[0,1:]-rbf_nodes[0,:-1]))


# kernel & derivative
rbf = lambda r:1/(1+(r/sigma)**2)
Drbf = lambda r: -2*r*sigma**2/(sigma**2 + r**2)**2

#compute coefficients of rbf network
r = np.abs(xi[:, None]-rbf_nodes)
A = rbf(r)
coeffs = np.linalg.lstsq(A, yi, rcond=None)[0]
print(coeffs)

#evaluate rbf network
N=1000
xe = np.linspace(xi.min(), xi.max(), N)
Ae = rbf(xe[:, None] - rbf_nodes)
ye = Ae @ coeffs


#evaluate derivative
N=1000
xd = np.linspace(xi.min(), xi.max(), N)
Bd = Drbf(xe[:, None] - rbf_nodes)
yd = Bd @ coeffs


fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

ax.plot(xv, yv, '-')
ax.plot(xi, yi, '-')
ax.plot(xe, ye, ':')

ax2.plot(xd, yd, '-')

fig.savefig('graph.png')
print('done')
```

[image]

Comment: Looking at the input curve I'd expect that OP's true cdf has a monotonically decreasing derivative, which would mean that the local maximum in your blue curve (as well as the wiggles in the tail) is an artifact of the procedure. I'd try using some curve fitting procedure to get an analytical fit on the raw data and taking the derivative of that. I guess I'd either try to guess an analytical function (something exponential, of course), or give up and use something like a piecewise Hermite interpolator.

Comment: I tend to agree with @AndrasDeak, regularized PDF given CDF should look like exponential or Paretto

Comment: Yes the pdf should be monotonic in this case.

Comment: If you zoom in on the curve you can actually see that the derivative is now a little bit lower at first and gets higher after. But if you still consider this part of the noise you can inrease the smoothness parameters, and maybe add some more nodes outside of the desired domain. An alternative is to use normalized RBFs, so the basis actually forms a partition of the unity.

Answer (score 1):

You need the derivative to go from CDF to PDF

```
PDF(x) = d CDF(x)/ dx
```

With NumPy, you could use [gradient](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)

```
pdf = np.gradient(yvalues, xvalues)
plt.plot(xvalues, pdf)
plt.show()
```

or manual differential

```
pdf = np.diff(yvalues)/np.diff(xvalues)
l = np.asarray(xvalues[:-1])
r = np.asarray(xvalues[1:])
plt.plot((l+r)/2.0, pdf) # points in the middle of interval
plt.show()
```

Both produce something like, updated picture it got botched somehow

[image]

Comment: Shouldn’t the pdf look like a smooth curve in this case?

Comment: @Anush Well, it depends, and it depends on data. I made it in a simplest way possible, just to show the idea. One could try smoother differentiation schemes, or data regularization technique(s) etc, and you could get smooth curve

Comment: why does a pdf have a y-value >1?